# Discord.py How to check MissingRequiredArgument Error?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want check MissingRequiredArgument Error.

I did this:

```
try:
    code..
except MissingRequiredArgument:
    await ctx.send('missing argument!')
```

Is this not?

Comment: Have you imported the error from `from discord.ext.commands import MissingRequiredArgument`?

Comment: ok,
Let's do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an error handler, example:

```py
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

# If you invoke it without an argument `commands.MissingRequiredArgument` is going to be thrown
# To handle discord.py errors
@foo.error # Name of the command + .error
async def foo_error(ctx, error):
    # Checking the type of the error
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        # Send something
        await ctx.send("...")
```

Handling in cogs is pretty similar, the only difference is that you pass `self` as the first argument

```py
class SomeCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def foo(self, ctx, arg):
        await ctx.send(arg)

    @foo.error
    async def foo_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            # Do something
```

[Introduction to error handling](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=commands#error-handling)

Comment: ok, thank you. but I use discord.py Cogs, How I do?

Comment: Same way but you also add `self` as the first argument in the error handler, let me edit my answer

Comment: Edited my answer, remember to accept it if it helped